# Editor sent a mail asking me to revise my submission based on reviewer comments. the reviewer comments were missing. What to do?

Tags: publications

I got a mail from the editor asking me to revise my manuscript according to reviewer recommendations. There were no reviewer comments in the mail . I then mailed the editor asking about this. He replied back with the exact same reviewer comments from the previous round.
I mailed the senior editors of the journal. One of them replied saying that they apologize for the situation and the chief editor will contact me. 5 days have passed since and I have got no reply.
I have mailed the journal office now. Its a decent journal from Elsevier. I don't know what to do now. The manuscript has already undergone 3 rounds of review and 2 reviewers have recommended publication. The third reviewer was also satisfied and had suggested very minor corrections.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? Maybe even a question random academics on the internet can answer? It sounds like a technical hiccup that needs to be sorted out by the editors.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to stop emailing people and just wait patiently for a response.

It seems to me the original editor may have just made a mistake and sent the wrong set of comments.  At that point, you could have simply replied to him, saying "Thanks, but these appear to be the comments from the previous round, which are already addressed in my latest revision.  Were there comments from the latest round?"

Instead, you escalated to the senior editors.  Now they are going to have to communicate with the original editor to understand what is going on, probably sending several emails back and forth between themselves.  Five days is not nearly enough time for this to happen.  Keep in mind that all the editors are most likely professors who are busy with full-time teaching and research duties; journal editorship is usually unpaid volunteer work, and will not be their highest priority.  And now you have escalated to the journal office, which adds yet one more set of people who have to be brought up to speed; that will make it take even longer.

At this point, I think anything further you try to do will only make things worse.  So just wait until somebody contacts you.  It could be several weeks; just be patient.  When you do get a response, answer any questions they have, and if it seems like they have misunderstood the situation, then explain it as clearly as you can.  But don't involve any more people.  There is a risk that they start to consider you as "troublesome" and might decide to just reject your paper rather than dealing with you further; it could also prejudice them against future papers you might submit to this journal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The last date for submitting a revised version is nearing which is why is mailed the journal office.